# Expanding a Scribunto module that doesn't have a function

Tags: python, lua, wikitext, scribunto

I want to get the return value of this Wikimedia [Scribunto module](https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/Modul:Languages) in Python. Its source code is roughly like this:

```lua
local Languages = {}

Languages = {
    ["aa"] = {
        name = "afarština",
        dir = "ltr",
        name_attr_gen_pl = "afarských"
    },
    -- More languages...
    ["zza"] = {
        name = "zazaki",
        dir = "ltr"
    }
}

return Languages
```

In the Wiktextract library, there is already [Python code](https://github.com/tatuylonen/wiktextract/blob/master/get_languages.py) to accomplish similar tasks:

```py
def expand_template(sub_domain: str, text: str) -> str:
    import requests

    # https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Expandtemplates
    params = {
        "action": "expandtemplates",
        "format": "json",
        "text": text,
        "prop": "wikitext",
        "formatversion": "2",
    }
    r = requests.get(f"https://{sub_domain}.wiktionary.org/w/api.php",
                     params=params)
    data = r.json()
    return data["expandtemplates"]["wikitext"]
```

This works for languages like French because there the Scribunto module has a well-defined function that returns a value, as an example here:

Scribunto module:

```lua
p = {}

function p.affiche_langues_python(frame)
-- returns the needed stuff here
end
```

The associated Python function:

```py
def get_fr_languages():
    # https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:langues/analyse
    json_text = expand_template(
        "fr", "{{#invoke:langues/analyse|affiche_langues_python}}"
    )
    json_text = json_text[json_text.index("{") : json_text.index("}") + 1]
    json_text = json_text.replace(",\r\n}", "}")  # remove tailing comma
    data = json.loads(json_text)
    lang_data = {}
    for lang_code, lang_name in data.items():
        lang_data[lang_code] = [lang_name[0].upper() + lang_name[1:]]

    save_json_file(lang_data, "fr")
```

But in our case we don't have a function to call.
So if we try:

```py
def get_cs_languages():
    # https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/Modul:Languages
    json_text = expand_template(
        "cs", "{{#invoke:Languages}}"
    )
    print(json_text)
```

we get `<strong class="error"><span class="scribunto-error" id="mw-scribunto-error-0">Chyba skriptu: Musíte uvést funkci, která se má zavolat.</span></strong> usage: get_languages.py [-h] sub_domain lang_code get_languages.py: error: the following arguments are required: sub_domain, lang_code`. (Translated as "You have to specify a function you want to call. But when you enter a function name as a parameter like in the French example, it complains that that function does not exist.)

What could be a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most general way is to get the return value of the module as JSON and parse it in Python.

Make another module that exports a function `dump_as_json` that takes the name of the first module as a `frame` argument and returns the first module as JSON. In Python, expand `{{#invoke:json module|dump_as_json|Module:module to dump}}` using the [`expandtemplates` API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Expandtemplates) and parse the return value of the module invocation as JSON with `json.loads(data["expandtemplates"]["wikitext"])`.

Text of `Module:json module` (call it what you want):

```lua
return {
    dump_as_json = function(frame)
        local module_name = frame.args[1]
        local json_encode = mw.text.jsonEncode
        -- json_encode = require "Module:JSON".toJSON
        return json_encode(require(module_name))
    end
}
```

With `pywikibot`:

```py
from pywikibot import Site
site = Site(code="cs", fam="wiktionary")
languages = json.loads(site.expand_text("{{#invoke:json module|dump_as_json|Module:module to dump}}")
```

If you get the error `Lua error: Cannot pass circular reference to PHP`, this means that at least one of the tables in `Module:module to dump` is referenced by another table more than once, like if the module was

```lua
local t = {}
return { t, t }
```

To handle these tables, you will have to get a pure-Lua JSON encoder function to replace `mw.text.jsonEncode`, like the `toJSON` function from [Module:JSON](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:JSON) on English Wiktionary.

One warning about this method that is not relevant for [the module you are trying to get](https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/Modul:Languages): string values in the JSON will only be accurate if they were NFC-normalized valid UTF-8 with no special ASCII control codes (U+0000-U+001F excluding tab U+0009 and LF U+000A) when they were returned from `Module:module to dump`. As on a wiki page, the `expandtemplates` API will replace ASCII control codes and invalid UTF-8 with the U+FFFD character, and will NFC-normalize everything else. That is, `"\1\128e" .. mw.ustring.char(0x0301)` would be modified to the equivalent of `mw.ustring.char(0xFFFD, 0xFFFD, 0x00E9)`. This doesn't matter in most cases (like if the table contains readable text), but if it did matter, the JSON-encoding module would have to output JSON escapes for non-NFC character sequences and ASCII control codes and find some way to encode invalid UTF-8.

If, like the module you are dumping, `Module:module to dump` is a pure table of literal values with no references to other modules or to Scribunto-only global values, you could also get its raw wikitext with the [Revisions API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Revisions) and parse it in Lua on your machine and pass it to Python. I think there is a Python extension that allows you to directly use a Lua state in Python.

Running a module with dependencies on the local machine is not possible unless you go to the trouble of setting up the full Scribunto environment on your machine, and figuring out a way to download the module dependencies and make them available to the Lua state. I have sort of done this myself, but it isn't necessary for your use case.

Comment: Lua starts at 1, not 0, so it should be `frame.args[1]`.

Comment: @tweetotaler Corrected. Weird error because I've worked with Lua so much...